# Using quickForm with a collection and separate schema at the same time does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, forms, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

I want to store a time value in seconds in the DB.

In the form, the user should be able to type it as a String (MM:SS). After submission the String (MM:SS) should be transformed into seconds. That is why the schema the form is validated against differs from the schema used to validate against in the backend (right before writing it to the database).

So I did what is supposed here (https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#autoform-1) and I defined two schemas, one for the form (with time.type = "String") and another one that I attached to the collection (time.type = Number).

In the template I set **both parameters**, `collection="TimeItem"` and `schema="SpecialFormSchema`.

In the end, the **form always renders with a HTML Number input field and ignores the form schema**.

Can anybody help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually works as it should. My silly mistake was to experiment with different templates and worked on the wrong one and therefore did not see any results.

The working javascript:

```
// schema for collection
var schema = {
    time: {
        label: "Time (MM:SS)",
        type: Number // !!!
    },
    // ...
};
SongsSchema = new SimpleSchema(schema);
Songs.attachSchema(SongsSchema);

// schema for form validation
schema.time.type = String // changing from Number to String!
SongsSchemaForm = new SimpleSchema(schema);
```

What the template looks like:

```
{{>quickForm
   id="..."
   type="insert"
   collection="Songs"
   schema="SongsSchemaForm"
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The collection and schema are not supported together. You have to pick one or the other.

Try using hooks to do what you're trying to do:
https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks

Comment: You can't use both with a single form

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But what do you mean? Is it not possible to have them both installed at the same time? Or to use them both with the same form? The description of both of the packages seem to point out that this should not be a problem.

And the autoform manual supposes:

"This schema will be used to generate and validate the form prior to submission, so **you can specify this along with a collection if you want** to use a schema that is slightly different from the one your collection uses. However, the final object will still have to pass validation against the collection schema."

Comment: And this behaviour is exactly what I want... I thought about using a schema ("SimpleSchema" like in the autoform manual) for the form validation (String) and use the collection for validation in the backend after I transformed String into a Number.

I still might be wrong, but how would you interpret the lines I cited in my comment above? To me it sounds like using a collection "**along with**" a SimpleSchema should be no problem...

Comment: You're right. That is what the documentation says. Maybe try posting issue on the autoform github repo if you don't work it out.

Comment: You still need a way to convert the string to a number. I think one submit hooks could be a good place to do that

Comment: Maybe if you edit your answer to show some code it'll be easier to find a solution.

Comment: I will... and I will post the answer here.

Comment: Oh, thanks. But using the hooks is no big deal, I already am using them. It's just my usecase of different validations.